# TableView Duplicates and firebase search query

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two issues with the snippet below.

1. I have get duplication in my TableView.
2. When I search for something that returns a result, and I tried searching for another thing that returns a result, the existing result will be the one showing not the new result, for example:

   a. I search for "ola" and my TableView returns a list of -> olabode, olatunde, olaide.

   b. Then I searched for "bisi", if found matching query for "bisi" I still get the query result for "ola".

   ```
   func searchView(_ searchView: AZSearchViewController, didTextChangeTo text: String, textLength: Int) {
       self.resultArray.removeAll()
       searchView.reloadData()

   guard text != "" else {
       return
   }    
       AppFirRef.userRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "username")
           .queryStarting(atValue: text)
           .queryEnding(atValue: text + "\\uf8ff")
           .observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
               if (snapshot.value is NSNull) {
                   print("not found")
               } else {
                   print("found")
                   self.resultArray.removeAll()
                   searchView.reloadData()

                   print("\(snapshot.value)")
                   for case let snap as FIRDataSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                       guard let value = snap.value as? [String : Any] else { continue }
                       //print("\(snap.key)")
                       print(value)
                       let user = LContact(value: value, searchUserId: snap.key)
                       self.set.add(user)
                       if let username = user.username{
                           self.resultArray.append(username.lowercased())
                           searchView.reloadData()
                       }
                   }

               }
           })

   }
   ```

Comment: are you removing the rows from the TableViewSource before adding new data?

Comment: @apineda i noticed that the duplication occurs, when for instance. Taking two different devices, if device A is adding to "users" node, it will cause duplication in the lists of users in device B, until i restart device b before the duplication goes away, so basically my query will return duplicate if "users" node is being referenced from another device

Answer (score 1):

It might be too late, but change

```
.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
...
)}
```

to

```
.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
...
)}
```

see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45488598/firebase-multiple-observer-duplicates-cell/45493324#45493324) for the explanation; it applies to you as well because you are also appending to the array every time the data at your reference path changes (such as when someone on another device changes data in the `userRef` reference path.