# Firebase Multiple observer duplicates cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I want to show current user friends in tableView but I couldn't get it to work perfect, The cell duplicate when someone in the list change his name.

JSON:

```
    {
  "users" : {
    "friends_requests" : {
      "EeLIxkOEfhMUlsM8WGnHdgeT8xW2" : {
        "friends" : {
          "WWOdh96Yr3Qs4N3GWDVq3OlQFfB2" : true
        }
      },
      "WWOdh96Yr3Qs4N3GWDVq3OlQFfB2" : {
        "friends" : {
          "EeLIxkOEfhMUlsM8WGnHdgeT8xW2" : true
        }
      }
    },
    "profile" : {
      "EeLIxkOEfhMUlsM8WGnHdgeT8xW2" : {
        "birthday" : "02/08/2017",
        "displayname" : "user2",
        "email" : "11@1.1",
        "gender" : "M"

      },
      "WWOdh96Yr3Qs4N3GWDVq3OlQFfB2" : {
        "birthday" : "02/08/2017",
        "displayname" : "user1",
        "email" : "112@2.1",
        "gender" : "M"
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Here's the code:

```
var friendList = [Userr]()
func addFriendObserver(_ update: @escaping () -> Void) {
    CURRENT_USER_FRIENDS_REF.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.friendList.removeAll()


        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {



            self.ref.child("users").child("profile").child(rest.key).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
                    return
                }




                let user = Userr()

                user.displayname = dictionary["displayname"] as? String

                 self.friendList.append(user)


                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                }



            }, withCancel: nil)
```

I've tried many ways and asked this question many times but still couldn't get it to work and no answers.

Please could someone help me to fix this.

**Edit:** New observer i use:

```
 func showUsersObserver(_ update: @escaping () -> Void) {
CURRENT_USER_FRIENDS_REF.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    self.friendList.removeAll()


    let keys = snapshot.children
    while let rest = keys.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {



        self.getUser(rest.key, completion: { (user) in
            self.friendList.append(user)

            print(self.friendList.count) // This increase each time when user changing his name! or any changes hits his profile.

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }

            update()
        })

    }



    // If there are no children, run completion here instead
    if snapshot.childrenCount == 0 {
        update()
        }
    })
}
```

And this to get their profile data:

```
func getUser(_ userID: String, completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {
    USER_REF.child(userID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
            return
        }



        let id = dictionary["uid"] as? String
        let email = dictionary["email"] as? String
        let DisplayName = dictionary["displayname"] as? String




        completion(User(userEmail: email!, userID: id!, userDisplayName: DisplayName!))



    })
}
```

And friendList:

```
class User {

var uid: String!
var displayname: String!
var email: String!


init(userEmail: String, userID: String, userDisplayName: String) {

    self.email = userEmail
    self.uid = userID
    self.displayname = userDisplayName

    }
}
```

I was using Userr for testing. but User is main swift file.

Comment: Look into `self.friendList.removeAll()` try printing `friendList.count` right after to see if all users are removed. Also you should include the Userr class with your code

Comment: @Stefan thanks, I've tested that and its emptying the list. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
self.ref.child("users").child("profile").child(rest.key).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
...
})
```

to

```
self.ref.child("users").child("profile").child(rest.key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
...
})
```

`.observe` causes the code in the `...` to run every time data at your reference path is changed. As a result, you append to `friendList` every time data at the reference path is changed. `.observeSingleEvent` ensures that code is only executed once.

If you want the cells to be updated whenever a user's data changes, keep using `.observe` and do this inside the closure:

**Make User have a property called uid for the user's push key**

```
guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
    return
}
let userID = snapshot.key
if let friend = self.friendsList.first(where: {$0.uid == userID}) {
    friend.displayname = dictionary["displayname"] as? String
    friend.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
    friend.uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String
    //update any other properties of the User class
    completion(friend)
}
else {
    let id = dictionary["uid"] as? String
    let email = dictionary["email"] as? String
    let displayName = dictionary["displayname"] as? String
    //update other properties of the User class

    let user = User(userEmail:email, userID:id, userDisplayName:displayName)
    self.friendsList.append(user)
    completion(user)
}
```

That code will make it so that any time a user's profile changes, it will check if any of the users in the `friendsList` array have the same userID, and if it does, it updates the matching userID user's displayname. If no user in the `friendsList` matches the userID, it will append the user to the end of `friendsList` because it is a new user that isn't in the array yet.

Comment: Thanks, I've did that but names wont be updates until current user open the viewcontroller again, I want user's name update each time they change their name like i want to see that changes in tableView directly.

Comment: Okay I'll update my answer to allow for that functionality, but first I need to know if it is possible for multiple users to have the same displayname? Is it unique to each user or can mulitple users have the same displayname?

Comment: If not, you might want to add `userID` as a property of `Userr` and set it equal to the pushID of the user (i.e "EeLIxkOEfhMUlsM8WGnHdgeT8xW2") because even in future scenarios, it will be useful to have a property that can uniquely distinguish one `Userr` from another.

Comment: @Sam Check the edited post. Add a property to the `Userr` class that is of type `String?` and is called `userID`.

Comment: thank you so much for helping, I got error with userID, I have edited my question and added new observer that i'm using it now with new User file. Could you check them and edit your answer please?

Comment: And users can have same displayname its not unique to each user, Also there is username which is unique.

Comment: I got this error: https://i.gyazo.com/c7cbff76137c0f33d828aa3398b766ca.png

Comment: It should not be `User().userID`. It should be `userID` which is the variable you declared a couple lines before that. That should fix the error in the picture.

Comment: Yah i've tried both same error. You can check my Friendlist in the question.

Comment: Since you named the property `uid` in your User class, do `$0.uid` instead of `$0.userID`. I'll edit my post to show what it should look like.

Comment: oh yes error gone now, should i add completion inside else{} ?

Comment: If you'll edit your answer also with the new observer that im using now it will be more helpful

Comment: I edited my answer to include all the properties you have in your `User` class and the completion, although if you do what I did, I don't think the completion is necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I hope you'll get success in your whole life.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!

Comment: One more question, I was wondering if the user have 300 friends and he was scrolling down and then if someone changed his name, All the table gonna be reloaded so it will cause a problem for the user? Because i was using animation for cell and i saw all the cells animate after someone change his name, any idea\info\ tips?

Comment: Yeah, you can reload the data for individual cells rather than the whole table. So if someone changes their username, you simply get the index of the friend in the the friendArray and then use that index value to reload its corresponding row instead of the entire table.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've got Array.index but i couldn't convert it to indexPath to reload specific cell, See the code here: https://i.gyazo.com/08cd9dbaf777d7d150533220eaf475fd.png Any help will be appreciate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151091/discussion-between-rpatel99-and-sam).